# Is Blue Bloods based off of a real family?

Tags: plot-explanation, blue-bloods

Is the series [*Blue Bloods*](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiK8dHJpIHLAhXE6RQKHYxyD4QQFggjMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FBlue_Bloods_(TV_series)&usg=AFQjCNETzVqRzmeR83FSc4Rywl9FnYzAuw) based off of a real-life family of law enforcement officers? Since I haven't been able to find a reference to the same.

And was the series named as a reference to nobility (often termed blue bloods) or as a reference to the blue police uniforms in NYC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the series Blue Bloods based off of a real-life family of law enforcement officers?

No. CBS has not stated that it has, and there has been no similar situated family dynasty of Cop/[Commissioner Father Son in the NYPD history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York_City_Police_Commissioner).

> And was the series named as a reference to nobility (often termed blue bloods) or as a reference to the blue police uniforms in NYC ?

Yes. The Reagans are considered *"royalty"* among the show's NYPD. It's a play on words.

Answer (score -4):

I am currently reading a book, Blue Blood, by Edward Conlon, NYPD retired. He was a Harvard alum (undergrad). Relative (or friend's father - I forget) was PC, his dad, FBI. Published in 2006. 560 pages, I'm on 150 - and it is excellent.

Has to be the inspiration for the TV series, but I cannot find any such reference. Too many similarities, ideas, concepts for it not to be. Conlon retired as detective. The book's jacket bio says he lives in the Bronx. Salute, Detective Conlon. Nicely done, sir.

Comment: Conlon's Wikipedia article claims, [with source](http://www.nypost.com/seven/11232007/gossip/pagesix/blood_money_386623.htm), that "[Blue Blood] was the basis of a 2007 television pilot that NBC commissioned but ultimately did not order." It doesn't mention anything about *Blue Bloods*. I think you're unfortunately mistaken.